# Compute product with rolling window

Tags: python, pandas, product, rolling-computation

I have a df:

| month | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1994-07 | 1 | 2 | NAN | NAN |
| 1994-08 | 5 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 1994-09 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 1994-10 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 |
| 1994-11 | 1 | NAN | 3 | 1 |
| 1995-07 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 4 |
| 1995-08 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |

I want, for each column, to get the product of a rolling window of size 5, ignoring NAN values. Which means, in this case:

| month | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1994-11 | 5 | 16 | 27 | 4 |
| 1995-07 | 5 | 16 | 54 | 16 |
| 1995-08 | 1 | 16 | 54 | 16 |

For D(1994-11), for example, I would get 4 (4*1*1*1), and C (1995-07) results in 54 (2*3*3*1*3). I have tried:

`df = df.rolling(window=5,axis=0).apply(prod(min_count=1))`

It is an attempt of applying the function product from pandas.

But I get the error "NameError: name 'prod' is not defined"

Answer (score 1):

I would use numpy product here.  NAN will be a string when we copy/paste it into our from your sample, so I went ahead and replaced it with `np.nan`.  From there you can replace `NaN` with 1, since it's a product if won't change the outcome, but will fulfill the rolling period requirement.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'month': ['1994-07',
  '1994-08',
  '1994-09',
  '1994-10',
  '1994-11',
  '1995-07',
  '1995-08'],
 'A': [1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 'B': ['2', '2', '2', '2', 'NAN', '2', '2'],
 'C': ['NAN', '3', '1', '3', '3', '2', '3'],
 'D': ['NAN', '4', '1', '1', '1', '4', '4']})


(
    df.replace('NAN',np.nan)
      .set_index('month')
      .fillna(1)
      .rolling(5)
      .apply(np.product)
      .dropna()
      .reset_index()
)
```

Output

```
     month    A     B     C     D
0  1994-11  5.0  16.0  27.0   4.0
1  1995-07  5.0  16.0  54.0  16.0
2  1995-08  1.0  16.0  54.0  16.0
```

Another option if you are worried about entirely null columns:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

window = 5

df = pd.DataFrame({'month': ['1994-07',
  '1994-08',
  '1994-09',
  '1994-10',
  '1994-11',
  '1995-07',
  '1995-08'],
 'A': [1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 'B': ['2', '2', '2', '2', 'NAN', '2', '2'],
 'C': ['NAN', '3', '1', '3', '3', '2', '3'],
 'D': ['NAN', '4', '1', '1', '1', '4', '4']})

df['C'] = np.nan
(
    df.replace('NAN',np.nan)
      .set_index('month')
      .rolling(window=window, min_periods=1)
      .apply(np.nanprod)
      .reset_index()
    
).iloc[window-1:]
```

Output

```
    month    A     B   C     D
4  1994-11  5.0  16.0 NaN   4.0
5  1995-07  5.0  16.0 NaN  16.0
6  1995-08  1.0  16.0 NaN  16.0
```

Comment: I have done this before. The problem is that in many cases the multiplication should be just nan*nan*nan*nan*nan which returns nan, but replacing nan by 1, the outcome is 1, which I do not want.

Comment: Added another option to handle a fully null column

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody comes to this: I have solved in the following way:
df = df.rolling(window=5, min_periods=1).apply(lambda x: np.prod(1 + x) - 1)